# Can I use Facebook translate service in my python NLP project?

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, nlp, facebook-javascript-sdk, translation

I hope you are feeling good and safe.

I'm working on Natural language processing project for my master degree, and I do need to translate
my local dialect to ENG, and I noticed that Facebook translate machine did very well with my local dialect.

So my question is there any way to use Facebook translate service in my project, like is there any api or python module that use it.

Answer (score 1):

Which language is your local language?

Facebook has many machine translation models, so it depends on how good it has to be and how much computing power you have. I am not sure if they offer their latest state-of-the-art ones that they use in their products as an independent translation tool as well.

### First Option: Run full models locally

One way would be using one of their models on huggingface (see the "Generation" part):
https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/model_doc/m2m_100#training-and-generation

They also have some easy-to-use pretrained models in their torch.hub module (but that probably doesnt cover your local language):
https://github.com/pytorch/fairseq/blob/main/examples/translation/README.md

### Second Option: APIs

As I said it depends on what quality you need, you could try out some easy-to-use (non-facebook) APIs and see how far that gets you, as this is much easier and you can use them online:

e.g. https://libretranslate.com/

Or check out this comparison of APIs: https://rapidapi.com/collection/google-translate-api-alternatives

APIs are usually limited to a maximum number of characters/words/requests per month/day/minute so you'll have to see if that is enough for your case and if the quality is acceptable.

### Third Option: pip packages which use APIs

For example check out: https://pypi.org/project/deep-translator/

### Fourth Option: pip wrapper packages which run translation locally

A great package which actually has some pretty strong facebook MT models is: https://pypi.org/project/EasyNMT/ (it also has their strong m2m_100 models)

More lightweight but probably not as strong: https://github.com/argosopentech/argos-translate

### Conclusion:

Since I assume your local language is not supported by that many models I would first try the fourth option (start with biggest models and if it doesnt work try smaller ones).

If that doesnt work out you can try if you can get APIs work for your case.

If you have a lot of computing power and want to go a bit deeper you can run the full model inference locally using huggingface or fairseq.

Comment: Thank you for your response its very helpful, my Lang is AR but we do speak a dialect which is not considered as a official language but we do use it in Facebook posts , comments .. and as I told you I noticed that Facebook is doing well with it I don't know what Facebook is considering it as AR or something else.
And for the solutions you gave me I tried the EasyNMT cause it has m2m-100 translation machine which is the same TM Facebook is using, but its not giving me the same result I tried to copy the same text which Facebook is translating it very well but I don't get the same result.

Comment: I see, I think this will depend on how the model was trained. In this case if the training data was very clean then it might have been limited to modern high Arabic. If the model was trained on user generated online content the training data included more different dialects/locales, which is better in this case (at least for the direction of AR->EN). You can see if your dialect has an official language code here: http://www.lingoes.net/en/translator/langcode.htm But in general Arabic is already a relatively low ressource language and the dialects have even much less ressources available.